# How to suppress popup message

Tags: php, html, iphone

I have added a phone link on my website with the following code:

```
  <a style='text-decoration:none' href='tel:<?php echo ${'skipCell' . $i}; ?>'>
  <img src="http://www.sailwbob.com/skipper/public/img/phone-48.png"  style="width:48px;height:48px;border:0;"></a>
```

The code works but I get a popup message that says:

```
This website has been blocked from automatically starting a call
```

I can choose to either Ignore and cancel the request or allow call which then works.  Is there a way to suppress the pop up message?  It seems to work on chrome without any problems but I keep getting this message on safari

Comment: This is a browser-specific feature. You must have cancelled allowing the browser to call one too many times. You'll need to find the option/flag in your browser options and clear it.

Comment: can you advise on the specific safari setting to change on a iphone?

Comment: That I would not know. Perhaps someone else will know, or reach out to apple care.

Comment: According to https://discussions.apple.com/message/30924255#30924255 this happens when you've canceled a call 3 times on the same site. It doesn't mention any way to edit the block list.